# Let $f(x)$ be a function so that $f$ is of class $C^\infty$ . Find the limit of ${\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)}^{(n)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a function so that $ f$ is of class $C^\infty$ and an integer $p\gt 0$ exists so that $f^{(p+1)} = f'(x)$.

Find the limit of ${\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)}^{(n)}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

What I did:

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\int_0^1f^{'}(tx)dt$ so ${\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)}^{(n)}=\int_0^1 t^nf^{(n+1)}(tx)dt$.

From here I thought that because $f^{(n+1)}(tx)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ it has to have a maximum value. Let $c$ be the point at which $f^{(n+1)}(tx)$ reaches that value.
$0\lt\int_0^1 t^nf^{(n+1)}(tx)dt \lt \int_0^1t^nf^{(n+1)}(c)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n+1}$.
But I can't say for sure that $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n+1}$tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. I thought that I have to use $p$ here somehow, but I can't figure it out.

Also the problem has some steps for solving it, in which it states that I must show that $f^{(n+1)}(tx)$ is uniformly bounded, and I don't know why or how to show this.

Comment: the existence of $p$ pretty much guarantees that the derivatives are uniformly bounded on $[0,1].$ If $n = (p+1)m+k, k\leq p$ then $f^{(n)}(x) = f^{(k)}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the existence of $p$ pretty much guarantees that the derivatives are uniformly bounded on $[0,1].$ If $n = (p+1)m+k, k\leq p$ then $f^{(n)}(x) = f^{(k)}(x)$ and so any derivative is bounded by: 
$$\max\limits_{0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq k\leq p}f'(x)<\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $p=3$ just to play around. The sequence of derivatives is then

$$f^{(1)},f^{(2)},f^{(3)},f^{(1)},f^{(2)},f^{(3)},\dots$$